# Is pg_class.relhastriggers a safe alternative to `ALTER TABLE ... DISABLE TRIGGER USER`?

Tags: postgresql

On my table I have a trigger which prevents updates, therefore meaning that rows are effectively immutable post insertion.

When needing to perform retrospective updates to this table (e.g. adding a new calculated field) I have taken the following approach:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table DISABLE TRIGGER USER;

UPDATE my_table
  SET x = (...);

ALTER TABLE my_table ENABLE TRIGGER USER;
```

The downside to this approach is that it requires an AccessExclusiveLock.

I was wondering if the following is safe for me to use given it is guaranteed that the rows in the `UPDATE` will not be being updated by other queries:

```
BEGIN;
  UPDATE pg_class
    SET relhastriggers = FALSE
    WHERE relname = 'my_table';

  UPDATE my_table
    SET x = (...);

  UPDATE pg_class
    SET relhastriggers = TRUE
    WHERE relname = 'my_table';
COMMIT;
```

What I have tried so far suggests this is safe and that outside of this transaction the triggers will continue to be applied as normal.

Also, if it is indeed safe for my use case what are the circumstances in which it would not be safe?

I am using **Postgres 9.4.8**.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating `relhastriggers` will behave more like `DISABLE TRIGGER ALL`, i.e. it will also disable the internal triggers used for foreign key and deferred uniqueness checks. This may or may not be an issue in your case.

I don't know if a direct update of `pg_class` might violate some assumption made in some corner of the Postgres codebase. But in general, hacking catalog tables is inherently unsafe; even if it doesn't break anything *now*, there is no guarantee that this will be the case in future versions.

[`REVOKE UPDATE ON my_table`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-revoke.html) is a far better approach for blocking updates. Superusers are automatically exempt, so anybody with permission to `UPDATE pg_class` will have no problem with `my_table`.

If, for whatever reason, you really do need to do this with a trigger, there is another (somewhat hacky, but at least supported) way of circumventing it. By default, triggers will not be fired by replication processes (though this can be controlled via the `ENABLE ALWAYS` clause of [`ALTER TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html)). This means that you can bypass the trigger by impersonating a replicator:

```
BEGIN;
  SET LOCAL session_replication_role TO replica;
  UPDATE my_table SET x = (...);
COMMIT;
```

As with the catalog update, this will also disable any internal constraint triggers.